# Google Earth, Firefox not adding .kml

Tags: php, firefox, download, kml

I'm creating some KML files on a web site and everything works well in all browsers except Firefox: the downloaded file is supposed to be someMap.kml, but Firefox just downloads this as 'someMap' without the '.kml'. Behavior in all other browsers is right, am I missing something?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$kml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<Placemark>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-103.71866226196289</longitude>
                <latitude>19.241143039165962</latitude>
                <altitude>10000</altitude>
                <heading>-0.00787786711370108</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>20</range>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>

            </LookAt>

        </Placemark>
<NetworkLink>

    <name>Posicion</name>
    <Link>
        <href>some URL</href>
        <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
        <refreshInterval>60</refreshInterval>
    </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</Document>
</kml>';


        header("Pragma: public"); 
        header("Expires: 0");       
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml kml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($kml));
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=someMap.kml"); 


echo $kml
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the other headers apart from Content-disposition and Content-Type.

You have the quote marks a little of on the Content-Disposition header as is, try wrapping the file name in quotes. Also, the content type should not have the charset set (at least I think not) Finally. you should remove any white space before the headers.

Try this.

```
 // rest of the file...
 </kml>';
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml kml');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="someMap.kml"');
 echo $kml;
 ?>
```